# Why Does Object Page Section Title Come in Capital Letters and How to Disable It

Tags: sapui5

When I try to add `ObjectPageSection` inside `<sections>` of an `ObjectPageLayout`, I see the title coming in capital letters.

Could anyone explain why? I would like to show it as title-cased.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.uxap"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:m="sap.m"
  xmlns:blockcolor="sap.uxap.sample.SharedBlocks"
  controllerName="personal.controller.Object"
  height="100%"
>
  <ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayout"
    enableLazyLoading="false"
    showAnchorBarPopover="false"
    showFooter="true"
  >
    <headerTitle>
      <ObjectPageHeader objectTitle="{DataAgingGroupName}"/>
    </headerTitle>
    <sections>
      <ObjectPageSection title="Section 2">
        <subSections>
          <ObjectPageSubSection title="Deletable Data Subjects">
            <blocks>
              <Table xmlns="sap.m" id="table"
                mode="SingleSelectLeft"
                width="auto"
                items="{invoice>/Invoices}"
                noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}"
                busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}"
                growing="true"
                growingScrollToLoad="true"
                updateFinished="onUpdateFinished"
              >
                <columns>
                  <Column id="nameColumn1">
                    <Text text="Data Subject"/>
                  </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                  <ColumnListItem
                    type="Navigation"
                    press="onPress"
                  >
                    <cells>
                      <Text id="__picker0"
                        text="{invoice>ProductName}"
                        width="100%"
                      />
                    </cells>
                  </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
              </Table>
            </blocks>
          </ObjectPageSubSection>
        </subSections>
      </ObjectPageSection>
      <ObjectPageSection title="Section 1">
        <subSections>
          <ObjectPageSubSection title="General Information"/>
        </subSections>
      </ObjectPageSection>
    </sections>
    <footer>
      <m:OverflowToolbar>
        <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
        <m:Button
          text="Delete"
          type="Reject"
          press="handleDelete"
        />
      </m:OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
  </ObjectPageLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and you **should** if you're following the Fiori Guidelines, [disable the uppercase](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/object-page/#anchor-bar-and-overflow1) via [`upperCaseAnchorBar`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/methods/setUpperCaseAnchorBar) since the default value is `true` there. The same goes for the `<ObjectPageSection>` which has the property [`titleUppercase`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection/methods/setTitleUppercase) enabled by default. So, disable them explicitly:

```xml
<ObjectPageLayout upperCaseAnchorBar="false" ...>
  <sections>
    <ObjectPageSection titleUppercase="false" ...>
```

The `<ObjectPageSubSection>`, on the other hand, provides the property `titleUppercase` too, but its default value is already `false` there.

Answer (score -1):

It comes from the css

```
.sapUxAPObjectPageSectionTitleUppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

:)